# How can I access the admin panel for the transaction service when using safe-global/safe-infrastructure?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

I want to deploy the Safe app on a custom EVM-compatible network using [the safe-infrastructure repository](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure).

Based on moisses89’s comment (https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/issues/211#issuecomment-1485365021), I should submit pull requests to the [safe-deployments](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/pull/209) and [safe-eth-py](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-eth-py/pull/500) repositories, which have now been merged. However, the new version of [web-core](https://github.com/safe-global/web-core/blob/4b2fe0ed470d26312a030d209fa75ff47e98b106/package.json#L47) and other libraries that safe-infrastructure depends on have not been released yet.

In this case, I need to use the admin panel for transaction service with Master Copies and Proxy Factories according to the guide. Could you please tell me how to access the admin panel and set it up for my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can watch this video, in the description section there are all the necessary links:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUytj_xStDI

Or you can just copy these )):

- Safe config admin interface: *http://localhost:8000/cfg/admin*
- Safe service admin interface: *http://localhost:8000/txs/admin*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).